# COLUMN SELECTION and VARIABLE ASSIGNMENT in single select

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, variables, select

I can assign value to variable and select column in single statement in MySQL like this

```
declare @i int= 0
select @i :=1 , col1 FROM Table
```

But can not do that in SQL SERVER.
As it gives the error

> A SELECT statement that assigns a value to a variable must not be combined with data-retrieval operations.

Please describe what is the underlying difference.

Comment: I think the error message is really clear on this one.  That is how SQL Server works.  A `SELECT` *either* returns a result set *or* it assigns variables, but not both.

Comment: These are two different products with different implementations and extensions of sql. You must not expect copy-pasted code from one of them to work in the other.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Wasn't this very thing how old Sql Server versions used to do string concatenation, though? Seems like Sql Server has been able to do this in the past.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn That was all variable assignment.  eg `select @n = @n + name from sys.objects`  The assignment is repeated for every row of the result, but nothing is returned to the client.

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft Isn't the variable assigment `SELECT @n += ...` undefined when combined with `ORDER BY expression`?

Comment: @LukaszSzozda It's bad form.  But so common it was eventually documented. https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqltips/2005/07/20/ordering-guarantees-in-sql-server/